# Is there an easy way to import a class(TypeDefinition) to other assembly?

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I want to import a new class to an exist assembly. Now my solution is :

1. Write this class first and build it.
2. Then check its IL code in ILDASM.
3. Create new `TypeDefinition`,`Method
   Definition` and `Instruction` and then added to the exist assembly.

These would cost me a lot of time as I'm not good at IL and Mono.cecil.
SO I wonder that is there an easy way to import a TypeDefinition to another?like

```
var type = other_assembly.MainMoudle.Import(CLASS1).Reslove();
other_assembly.MainModule.Types.Add(type)
```

Comment: Do you want to do it at compile-time or at runtime? Is the import temporary or permanent?

Comment: Permanent.And runtime is better @codecaster

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the short answer for an easy way is "No". But there is hope.

The problem is that references to the original type are likely scattered throughout the generated IL for that type. An example would be in a property setter that updates the value of a private field. The field that is referenced in that setter is the field that lives in the original property. In fact, even the property setter for the property itself is a reference to a method within the original assembly's type.

To make this work, you need to look at every reference in the generated assembly (structure, variables, instructions, etc), and those that are self-referential must be updated to instead reference the newly created type.

I know that this is a hard problem because I've written code that does part of what you are looking for. My code actually copies the contents of a source type additively to a target type to enable mixins in C#. If you take the time to look over how the code works, then you could modify it. Here are some links to the Bix.Mixers code that you might find useful.

Project: https://github.com/rileywhite/Bix.Mixers.Fody

Structure Wireframe Clone: https://github.com/rileywhite/Bix.Mixers.Fody/blob/master/src/Bix.Mixers/Fody/ILCloning/ClonerGatheringVisitor.cs

Redirecting references from original to created type (see the RootImport methods): https://github.com/rileywhite/Bix.Mixers.Fody/blob/master/src/Bix.Mixers/Fody/ILCloning/ILCloningContext.cs